# Four power supplies in parallel to a bacon light?

Tags: power-supply

I have four machines at 24vdc and would like to have one light(e.g. tower) on when either machine is working or when all are working. This to happen, the light is connected independently to each ps, in this case all four ps become connected in parallel. 
Now the question is how would all four ps react to the light and to each other when let's say all four are powered up? It is also the case where all four ps's are not exactly 24vdc(one is 22.5). I have tested with #1 machine first and the light works fine; when connected #2 unit to the light, so two machines in parallel (but #1 was off, no pwr) the unit failed and I had to reboot. Here I put one forward diode on #1 machine on the +24vdc line and  tried again. This time there was no problem running #2, however #1 was still off. And here I stopped and looked for help online, but would be glad to see your input on this situation.

Comment: If I understand what you want to do correctly (?), you should put a diode on the output of each supply + output, tie the cathodes together and power the light from that node to ground.

Comment: Mmmmmmm, bacon.

Comment: @The Photon, once the bacon has been very well lighted you can't eat it anymore.

Comment: In the event of a power outage, it's very important to be able to save your bacon, and to do that you have to be able to find it in the dark.

Comment: I first heard about these lights on ham radio.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCuenJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Complete electrical isolation between machines can be achieved using relays.*

Pick the machine with the most reliable supply for the bacon light.

Add parallel relay contacts to the switch of the selected machine and feed the relay coils from each of the other machines. If the other machines have bacon lights they can be left in place, if required.

Comment: With four relays I can quite easy insulate all power supplies from each other and control the light in parallel. That was my initial idea and then I got the diodes..

Comment: The diodes don't insulate. They only prevent backfeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a 'light' can be a diffuser with an LED behind it.   And
there's no real reason not to get a large diffuser and put four
LEDs behind it.  So, just get some current limit resistors (for
24V power, assuming 10 mA will brightly light a white LED with
circa 3.5V drop, these would be about 2k ohms each) and
wire up four LEDs behind a frosted panel.  Don't intereconnect
(for instance) the common (ground) connections.   If you want
to get fancy, two 1kohm 1/4W fusible resistors, one in each
of the (+) and (-) legs of the LED circuit, and there's no 
possibility of excess current if the LEDs and wires get 
mangled or shorted.

Options: fluorescent panel and UV LEDs, blue or green or yellow LEDs (try
not to use red, that sometimes indicates fault).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really do not want to put four lights or four LED's. With nowadays level of automation, this should be fairly simple task... I just looked for someone opinion and experience.